# Rerun DAG Runs in order

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Let say I have a DAG scheduled to run daily and today is Sunday. Is there a way to tell Airflow to rerun all DAG Runs from Monday until today in order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the parameters: `depends_on_past` and `wait_for_downstream` for the dag, which will force the tasks to wait for the previous ones.
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/models/index.html#airflow.models.BaseOperator